# How can I make intersections for objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, intersection

I have a method that takes two objects. One of the points is the `@from_point`  and the other one is the `@to_point` . I have a method(`get_from_point`) that selects the point that has to be to `from_point` how can I assign `@to_point` if I already know which one of the  (point_one, point_two) is the `@from_point`

```
 def initialize(point_one, point_two)
    @from_point = get_from_point(point_one, point_two)
    @to_point = ???  
 end
```

Comment: Can you show us the `get_from_point` code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@to_point = @from_point == point_one ? point_two : point_one
```

But I'd advise to refactor your method to return both from and to so you can do this:

```
@from_point, @to_point = get_from_and_to_points(point_one, point_two)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

```
def initialize(point_one, point_two)
    @from_point,@to_point = [get_from_point(point_one, point_two),point_one, point_two].uniq
end
```

Here is some test :

```
x,y = [2,1,2].uniq
x # => 2
y # => 1
x,y = [1,1,2].uniq
x # => 1
y # => 2
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that won't work, right? You can only do Array - Array and even then the result will be an Array not a point.

Answer (score 0):

```
@to_point = [point_one, point_two].delete(@from_point).first
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any condition...

```
@from_point = get_from_point(point_one, point_two)
@to_point = (point_one + point_two) - @from_point
```